# How to make a form redirect to an URL given by the user in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

There are similar questions in stackoverflow, but not similar enough to help me solve my problem. I'm making a wikipedia-like website with Django, and would like to add a feature to enable the user to post their pages, just like in wikipedia. But the thing is, I want that when the user clicks the 'Add' button, he gets redirected to the page he just created. The URL to that page is the same as the title he gives in the form. This is the form definition:

```
class PageCreationForm(forms.Form):
     title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
     description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

     def get_title():
         return title
def createPage(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html", {"form":PageCreationForm()})
```

And the form usage in the HTML:

```
<h1>Create A New Wiki Page</h1>
<form action="{% url 'wikipedia:renderWikiPage' {{form.getTitle()}} %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

The URL 'renderWikiPage' needs the title of the page I want to render, and I tried to provide the title with **{{form.getTitle()}}**. Of course it did not work. How can I do that?

Comment: You don't you need to do that with JavaScript or with a "proxy" view that will make the redirect.

Comment: I do not think you declared your method `get_title()` correctly.  Shouldn't be `def get_title(self): return self.title` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **don't**. Django renders templates at the server side. So once the data is passed to the browser, Django no longer has control over that.

You need to do that with JavaScript or with a "proxy" view that will make the redirect. A simple redirect view could be something like:

```
from app_name.forms import PageCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def proxy_view(request):
    # …
    form = PageCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        return redirect('wikipedia:renderWikiPage', form.cleaned_data['title'])
```

You thus make a URL pattern for that view, and then let the form post to that views:

```
from app_name.views import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'wikipedia'

urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path('create/', proxy_view, name='create'),
]
```

The form then submits to the `proxy_view`:

```
<form action="{% url 'wikipedia:create' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```